# Convert XML Varchar Data to Image Type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I'm working on Reporting Service.

I need to update all reports, so I am converting all reports `Content` from `Image` type to `XML` type.

It works perfectly fine.

I have tried below, but it's not converting properly.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), REPLACE(XMLDATA,'<FontFamily>1</FontFamily>','<FontFamily>2</FontFamily>')))  FROM #a
```

Here, this contains my updated `XML` Data.

```
REPLACE(XMLDATA,'<FontFamily>1</FontFamily>','<FontFamily>2</FontFamily>'))
```

**In short, I want to do many replacement in same XML data**

For example, I have data something like below,

```
<Textbox Name="ID">
  <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
  <Paragraphs>
    <Paragraph>
      <TextRuns>
        <TextRun>
          <Value></Value>
          <Style>
            <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
            <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
          </Style>
        </TextRun>
      </TextRuns>
      <Style>
        <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
      </Style>
    </Paragraph>
  </Paragraphs>
  <rd:DefaultName></rd:DefaultName>
</Textbox>
```

Here I need to replace font family as well as font size and many more.

*So how can I do many replacement into XML data? Can you anyone please guide me.*

Comment: Thx for the edit... Very important: Are there many identical locations, and all of them are to be replaced with the same? Or are the many specific locations each of which gets a specific value? And second: Do you modify the text *within* the element **only**, or might there be a replacement of a full node (tags and content) or even of a full tree (tags and sub-tags)?

Comment: There are many identical location and yes all of them should be replaced with same. I want to modify the text with element only. I don't want to replace full node/full tree.

Comment: In this case the approach with `NVARCHAR` and `REPLACE` shoudl be better... Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type `IMAGE` is deprecated...

As is looks you are not converting to `XML` but to `(N)VARCHAR`. One *can* modify XML data on string level using string methods like replace, but - in most cases - it's better to use *real XML* with *XML DML* methods...

This small example should show you all casts you might need:

```
--this is a mock of your table with the IMAGE column with two rows
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,XmlData IMAGE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'<root><SomeData rowID="1"><FontFamily>1</FontFamily></SomeData></root>')
,(2,'<root><SomeData rowID="2"><FontFamily>2</FontFamily></SomeData></root>');

--The XmlData is casted to VARCHAR(MAX) as well as to XML
--The result is filled into a new table #tmpTable
SELECT ID
      ,XmlData AS ImageType
      ,CAST(XmlData AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS VarbinaryType
      ,CAST(CAST(XmlData AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VarcharMaxType
      ,CAST(CAST(XmlData AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS XmlType 
INTO #tmpTable
FROM @tbl;

--this is the actual content
SELECT * FROM #tmpTable;

--modify with string method
UPDATE #tmpTable SET VarcharMaxType=REPLACE(VarcharMaxType,'<FontFamily>1</FontFamily>','<FontFamily>99</FontFamily>');

--modify with XML-DML method
UPDATE #tmpTable SET XmlType.modify('replace value of (/root/SomeData[@rowID=1]/FontFamily/text())[1] with 99');

--the updated content
SELECT * FROM #tmpTable;

--and all converted back to IMAGE
SELECT ID
      ,ImageType
      ,CAST(VarcharMaxType AS IMAGE) AS VarcharMaxAsIMAGE
      ,CAST(CAST(XmlType AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS IMAGE) AS XmlTypeAsIMAGE
FROM #tmpTable;
GO

--Clean up
DROP TABLE #tmpTable;
```

Comment: Yes, you are abs right. I was converting to `(N)VARCHAR` - I have checked your sample answer. It will definitely work. But what will be the syntax for me to replace font family? - Using modify.

Comment: @pedram please give a more realistic example of the XML. Is there one or many places to replace?

Comment: many place to replace. Some part of my XML `<Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Verdana</FontFamily>
                                    <FontSize>9pt</FontSize>
                                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                  </Style>`

Comment: @pedram If you replace many occurrences of the same with all the same replacement use VARCHAR method. If you replace more specifically use XML dml. Please paste some *real* XML into your question and explain the *many replacement* with sample data

Comment: I have updated the question, is this okay? btw I have to use Varchar method as of now. Coz it seems XMLType.Modify will not be helpful in my case. Thank you so much for help... Simply great.. (y)